# How do keep my center divider consistently in the middle?

Tags: android

I have used a LinearLayout to create a center divider colored green as shown in the picture. I want to keep it consistently in the middle of the screen so it looks like one straight vertical line.

[image]

The list is created using a RecyclerView and also a RecyclerViewAdapter and uses my account_row.xml file to control the look of each row.

**account_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/accountLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/providerLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".99"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/providerTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"
            android:layout_weight=".02"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/usernameLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".99"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usernameTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I thought using weightsum and then setting the layout_weights for each would solve the problem but apparently that doesn't help. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:layout_width="0dp"` instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in  the child elements of a horizontal `LinearLayout` if you are using weight.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help. :)